# Why do I get this error? The provider could not determine the Double value

Tags: sql, vb.net, double

Why do I get this error:
The provider could not determine the Double value. For example, the row was just created, the default for the Double column was not available, and the consumer had not yet set a new Double value.

```
    ElseIf cb_Stat.Text = "Highest Goal/min" Then
        SQL = "SELECT Goals, Mins_Played, ((Mins_Played * 1.0) / Goals) AS gpm FROM PlayerDatabase"
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Connection)
        da.Fill(ds, "PlayerDatabase")
        lbl_Result.Text = ds.Tables("PlayerDatabase").Rows(0).Item(2)
    End If

    Me.lbl_Result.Left = Me.ClientSize.Width \ 2 - Me.lbl_Result.Width \ 2
    Connection.Close()
```

Comment: Your columns Goals contains a zero value.

Comment: What steve said, or it contains a non-double variable, such as null or NAN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your column Goals contains a zero value. In this case the correct error message should be `Division by Zero`, but Access gives back that not very useful error message.

Try with this query text.

```
Dim cmdText = "SELECT Goals, Mins_Played, " & _
              "iif([Goals] = 0, 0, (([Mins_Played]*1)/[Goals])) AS gpm " & _
              "FROM PlayerDatabase;"
```

AND if you need and order by, then you should repeat the expression used to build the gpm field

```
....
"FROM PlayerDatabase " & _
"ORDER BY (iif([Goals] = 0, 0, (([Mins_Played]*1)/[Goals]))) DESC;"
```

instead if you want to sort your data from code (thus not having the calc for gpm executed two times by the database) you can write

```
da.Fill(ds, "PlayerDatabase")
ds.Tables("PlayerDatabase").DefaultView.Sort = "gpm DESC"
lbl_Result.Text = ds.Tables("PlayerDatabase").DefaultView(0).Item(2)
```

Not sure if this is better (performance wise) than having the sort performed by the database engine. This needs to be tested when you have many rows to order.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the table to be ordered by gpm after the gpm has been calculated?

Comment: Order by and repeat the formula used to build the gpm field. You cannot use the field name.